# Using puppeteer to access body in HttpResponse designed to be downloaded as attachment

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I wish to use puppeteer to simulate clicking on a link which posts data to the server and returns a csv file designed to be downloaded by the user. When that response arrives, I would like to read and process the response payload (which I can see exists when looking at network traffic).

The response header includes:

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=GVG-SearchResults-20231205121846.csv
content-type: text/csv
```

the code I am currently using throws an error because there is no body detected in the response - I am assuming because of the `content-disposition` above:

```
const url = 'https://www.greenvehicleguide.gov.au/Vehicle/Search';
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
});
let page = await browser.newPage();

// select Toyota then Corolla and click submit
await page.goto(url, {timeout: 180000, waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
await page.waitForSelector('#VS_4_SelectedManufacturer option[value="3"]');
await page.select('#VS_4_SelectedManufacturer', '3');
const waitForSelectPop = 'https://www.greenvehicleguide.gov.au/Vehicle/GetNamesForSelectList';
await page.waitForResponse(waitForSelectPop);
await page.waitForSelector('#VS_4_VehicleModel option[value="Corolla"]');
await page.select('#VS_4_VehicleModel', 'Corolla');
await page.click('#submitType4');
await page.waitForNavigation();

// wait until the csv download link is available, click it and intercept response
const csvSelector = 'a.csv';
await page.waitForSelector(csvSelector);
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(
    response =>  response.headers()['content-disposition'] 
        && response.headers()['content-disposition'].startsWith('attachment')
);
await page.click(csvSelector);
const response = await responsePromise;
if (response.status() === 200) {
    console.log(response.headers()); // all good here
    const buffer = await response.buffer(); // throws
    // ... do stuff here which needs to run in a node context - processing and saving to fileSystem or database
}
```

this throws on the `response.buffer()` (`or response.text()`) with:

```
...\myProject\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\HTTPResponse.js:103
                    return Buffer.from(response.body, response.base64Encoded ? 'base64' : 'utf8');
                                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')
```

In summary - how do I obtain the body of the response and use it within the NodeJS context running pupeteer, overcoming the `content-disposition` of the response being `attachment`?

Answer (score 2):

The download seems to be triggered in JS, since the POST you're capturing isn't returning the data, either in Node or the network tab.

A workaround is to read the downloaded file and manipulate it from there:

```js
// using Node 18 and Puppeteer ^21.4.1
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const timers = require("node:timers/promises");

// ... your existing preparatory code ...

const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
  behavior: "allow",
  downloadPath: ".",
});

const tid = setTimeout(() => {
  throw Error("Timeout of 30000 ms exceeded waiting for GVG-SearchResults CSV");
}, 30_000);
await (await page.waitForSelector("a.csv")).click();

for (;;) {
  const reg = /^GVG-SearchResults-\d+\.csv$/;
  const csvName = (await fs.readdir(".")).find(e => reg.test(e));

  if (csvName) {
    clearTimeout(tid);
    const csv = await fs.readFile(csvName, {encoding: "utf-8"});
    await fs.unlink(csvName); // optionally remove the file
    console.log(csv);
    break;
  }

  await timers.setTimeout(200);
}
```

If you want to parse the CSV, run `npm i papaparse@^5.4.1` and add:

```js
console.log(require("papaparse").parse(csv));
```

I'll update this answer if I find a better approach (or feel free to post another answer--this is not a great solution, just *a* solution to keep things moving).

---

As an aside, I'd remove your `await page.waitForNavigation();` call. It can cause a race condition if the navigation occurs too quickly. Or else write it like this:

```js
const nav = page.waitForNavigation();
await page.click('#submitType4');
await nav; // note: this can only be awaited once! awaiting it again does nothing
```

Ditto for this code (I think, didn't look too closely):

```js
await page.select('#VS_4_SelectedManufacturer', '3');
const waitForSelectPop = 'https://www.greenvehicleguide.gov.au/Vehicle/GetNamesForSelectList';
await page.waitForResponse(waitForSelectPop);
```

Assuming the select change triggers a request, this should use the same pattern:

```js
const waitForSelectPop = 'https://www.greenvehicleguide.gov.au/Vehicle/GetNamesForSelectList';
const responseP = page.waitForResponse(waitForSelectPop);
await page.select('#VS_4_SelectedManufacturer', '3');
const response = await responseP;
```

For posterity, here's a related error on Puppeteer's GitHub: [Cannot read property 'body' of undefined #7562](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7562).

Comment: Wow - thank you very much!!!